# Syntax error in database (dictionary) (Python)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, syntax-error

I am trying to insert the last name value into the "test" table, but I am getting an exception. My problem is that I cannot insert the string representation of the dictionary into the table.

```
Exception thrown: OperationalError
next to "Surname": syntax error
```

My code:

```
con = sql.connect('test.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (`name` STRING, `surname` STRING)")
    name = input("Name\n> ")
    surname = str({'Surname': 1})
    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ('{name}', '{surname}')")

    con.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: surname is getting value as `{'Surname': 1}` , are you trying to save  value `{'Surname': 1}` in surname field of the table?

Comment: You can use backticks around table and field names (although they aren't required here), but you must use double quotes around field values.  You have asked for one piece of input, `name`.  What is `surname` supposed to be?  Because what you have is not doing it.

Comment: Please use parametrized queries (exact syntax depends on the library) instead of raw string substitution, which is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using placeholders will free you from the need to sanitize your input (and muck around with quotes), as well as protecting you from SQL injection attacks.

By the line `con = sql.connect('test.db')` I'm guessing that you're using [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). If you aren't the same principle should still hold, but the exact syntax for the placeholder may vary:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (?, ?)", (name, surname))
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I am using sqlite